# Retrieve and install pending certificate by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cert-manager

I am requesting a certificate that must be approved by the CA administrator.

When I make the request, it appears in the CA pending request folder and I right click to issue the certificate.
In client machine I want doing by PowerShell what I do in certmg.msc(Automatically Enroll and Retrieve Certificates):

Select top node (Certificates), right-click -> All Tasks -> Automatically Enroll and Retrieve Certificates. Follow certificate enrollment wizard to retrieve and install pending certificate.

Comment: and what is the business related question?

Comment: I have a script in PowerShell that makes certificate renewal request on a client machine, the script works fine and then I go to my CA to issue the request and then I need to do the similar in PowerShell which is done by certmgr "Automatically Enroll and retrieve certificates "

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-config` parameter of `certreq` to avoid using the GUI.

`-retrieve <requestid>` Retrieves a response to a previous request from a certificate authority. Pending Requests can be listes with `Get-PendingRequest` (PowerShell).

For example:

```
certreq -config "CAHostName\CAName" -retrieve 3499 "d:\test.cer"
```

Fetches the certificate for request.

```
certreq -accept "D:\test.cer" -machine
```

`–accept` links the previously generated private key with the issued certificate and removes the pending certificate request from the system where the certificate is requested (if there is a matching request).